# Point of concurrency of tangents at point of intersection

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

If the family of integral curve of $\frac{dy}{dx} + x^3y =x$ is cut by line $x=2$ then the tangent at the point of intersection are concurrent at which point?

Can this question be solved without solving differential equation because while
solving the equation I got $\int e^{\frac{x^4}{4}} \cdot x \cdot dx$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equation of the tangent at the point $(2,y_0)$ is

$$y=\frac{dy}{dx}|_{(2,y_0)}(x-2)+y_0$$

$$=(2-8y_0)(x-2)+y_0$$

$$=y_0(17-8x)+2(x-2)$$

so the intersection point is $$(\frac{17}{8},\frac{1}{4})$$